# Limit the number of notifications in status bar iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, notificationcenter

How can I limit the number of notifications shown in status bar? To be more precise I want to limit my app to only have one notification in status bar at a time. I want the latest notification replace the previous notification produced by my app.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, as a developer you have no control over the notification center.